# Why is Google Play Books incompatible with my Nexus 5?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-play-books

[image: Google Play Books incompatible my Nexus 5]

Today, I have bought a Nexus 5, and I want to download Google Play Books from Google Play, but I get the prompt message as seen in the above image.

Why am seeing this message and how can I install the app on my phone?

Comment: Isn't there already a Google Play Books app on your Nexus 5? The one it comes with may not be compatible with the one on Google Play.

Comment: It might not be available in your country.

Comment: @roxan Google Play isn't available at all in China, so the error message is a little confusing in that case.

Comment: Thanks guys,
When I use VPN network access Google Play, Everything is OK.
The Google Play Books default disabled on my Nexus5. If I use VPN network login Google Account that I can enable it.

Comment: If you hit the install button and mouse over your device on the list, it'll give you a buy more detailed reason why it is incompatible.

Comment: Use [APK Downloader](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) to download the .apk file, which you can then transfer to and install on your N5 like any other app.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Books comes pre-installed on Nexus 5, at least here in the Netherlends. If you do not have it nor can install it via Play Store I would guess that it is a country/operator restriction.